# No route matches [GET] for "showdown.min.js.map"

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, routes

I am setting up an existing rails application in my local machine. Whenever I hit a particular controllers' actions I am getting No route matches for showdown.min.js.map.

```
Started GET "/binary/createRepository/showdown.min.js.map" for 192.168.50.1 at 2018-05-18 09:35:21 +0000

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/binary/createRepository/showdown.min.js.map"):
actionpack (4.2.8) 
lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.8) 
lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.2.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.2.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in 
`block in tagged'
```

I checked that I have jquery-rails gem. Below are the gems that I have related to jquery.

```
 # Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
```

For every request it keeps logging in my dev log. But I do not see any behavioural changes because of this error. How do I get rid of this error from my log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

showdown is a markup to html converter [(here)](https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown)

I would just put the min.js file in the respective folder and be done with it. :)